# Is it appropriate to request a salary raise after trial/probation period is complete?

Tags: salary, negotiation, germany, probation

Working as a JavaScript Developer in Germany with an unlimited contract but of course with the usual 6 months probation period which i am 4 months in. (first job in Germany, I am a foreigner here)

Supposing my probation period ends successfully and I continue as a normal employee, would it be appropriate to ask for a raise say, 10-15% in terms of yearly salary?

For some more background: so far everything looks and feels great. The feedback from the team and the management is very positive. I have 2.5 years of working experience. And as a disclaimer, I am not feeling underpaid or anything along those lines. I simply want to know if it is appropriate to do so or not?

I checked other relevant questions to mine, but in my opinion, none really fit the context of my question.

Edit: Percentage amount was chosen arbitrarily because of not being informed properly before asking.

Comment: When you agreed to a salary before signing the contract: did they agree to pay you what you wanted or do they pay less?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler They agreed to pay me what I wanted. As I have stated in my question, I am not feeling underpaid or paid less than usual. Just wanted to know if this thing is appropriate to do or not and the other insights that may follow it.

Comment: I think this depends whether you were recruited on the market rate for someone with your experience, or on some lower 'trainee' rate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to request a salary raise after trial/probation period is complete?

IMO asking for a raise after only 6 month, regardless of performance, could be seen as a little greedy, since you already had your 'Lohnverhandlung' (salary-discussion) during the hiring process just a couple of months ago.

You and the company agreed on the terms and the amount of compensation for the role you've been employed for, and it would be hard for you to argue that you improved so vastly in performance and expertise during the past 6 months that would qualify you for a raise after such a short period (assuming no change to a higher role and that no additional responsibilities have been added to your plate).

But feel free to ask your manager if you think you deserve (in the context above) a raise, but be prepared that you most likely will be turned down after such a short period. In our company (Austria) we conduct yearly salary checks, so you could wait for another 6 months for a full year to pass and then speak to your manager.

Comment: I agree. You had a negotiation and you agreed to a certain salary for a certain kind of work. Finishing the probation shows that you can indeed do the work as agreed. Now, if during the probation it showed that you're actually much better at the job then originally estimated during the interview, then that might be a reason to give a raise or reassign you to a higher seniority rank (with higher pay).

Comment: I appreciate the insight and the suggestion. I have no information regarding salary checks and the periods it may be done though. Should I just ask then for general information regarding salary checks?

Comment: @minus.273 I would casually speak to your manager how and when salaries are evaluated - nothing wrong with asking if you are not yet aware of all internal proceedures..

Comment: Agree here, I wouldn't expect a discussion around raises until at least 12 months

Answer (score 5):

You are suggesting 10-15% after 6 months, there I would say in general no, not appropriate. In the first few months at a new company you still need to learn how everything works, what the projects are, familiarize yourself with everything. That means you are creating little to no value for the company. That's normal and expected, so no reason to worry about it. But it also means that only after these first few months you are actually worth your salary to the company although they had to pay it to you from day one.

I would recommend to wait for one full year for the first salary negotiation. Then the company can judge much better how good and useful to them you are. In general, asking for  something like 5 to 10% after one year is appropriate, although you might get a lot less. If you want more than that you need to provide very good reasons why you should be getting that.

Comment: This answer points out probably the biggest issue - the amount OP is asking for (10%-15%) is very high. Only an exceptional achievement could warranty that much IMO.

Comment: @Simon I agree the amount is unreal, kind of chose it arbitrarily. My bad. I should have asked another question regarding the amount i suppose, but now i know better. Will update the question. The amount was not the focus either way.

Answer (score 2):

> *I simply want to know if it is appropriate to do so or not?*

It is only appropriate, if it can be justified. If you believe you're worth of getting paid more, prepare a case and present it to your boss and ask for a raise.

Two things to keep in mind:

- Don't expect a raise because you *feel* like getting a raise.
- Don't be shy to ask for a raise if you feel you deserve one.

Usually, it's normal that every time an employee transitions to a new (higher) role, the salary and benefits are revised - but that's not a norm (unless mentioned in a contract). A raise does not need a change in position / designation, **and**, a change of position / role does not automatically guarantee a raise.